# Последние комментарии

Tags: mysql, select, sql

Делаю блок Последние комментарии

```
$com10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id",$connect);
$rowcom10 = mysql_fetch_array($com10);
```

и получаю последние 10 комментов, но если все комменты к одной новости то получится ссылки получаются на одну.

а как сделать что бы поле в котором лежит id новости (news) не повторялось два раза в выборке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` GROUP BY `news` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что искал

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: не в этом вопрос
сейчас получаю примерно такую инфу

- коммент 1 - новость 1-
- коммент 2 - новость 1-
- коммент 3 - новость 2-
- коммент 4 - новость 1-

получается три коммента из одной новости, а нужно что бы было

- коммент 1 - новость 1-
- коммент 2 - новость 2-
- коммент 3 - новость 3-
- коммент 4 - новость 4-